# Group extensions, Geometric group theory

Tags: geometric-group-theory

I am trying to learn a little bit of geometric group theory from the online lecture notes by Cornelia Drutu and Michael Kapovich titled geometric group theory. Here is the link https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/ggt.pdf. I am stuck trying to understand the following. I am sorry that i cannot establish the notations and terminology here. Look at page 37 first paragraph of the notes.

Let $G$ be a group with set of generators $X$ and with set of relations $R$ and $A$ any abelian group. Let $Y^2$ be the associated presentation complex. Now we embed $Y^2$ into a $3-$connected cell complex $Y$. It is claimed that $H^2(Y) = H^2(G,A)$.

I have the following questions:

(i) What is meant by attaching appropriate 3-cells. Does that in some way depend upon the abelian group A.

(ii) When computing cohomology of $Y$, how does $A$ comes into the picture.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the time to look into this fully, but by "attaching appropriate 3-cells", do they not just mean filling in the relators? Isn't that just the presentation complex? (I haven't actually read your link - I am just ad-libbing...)

Comment: From what i have understood. The elements of the group $G$ represent 1-cells and the relations form the 2-cells. Note that in the notes it is written that "Let $Y^2$ be the presentation complex" and after that they are attaching 3-cells, perhaps to make $Y^2$ a connected complex but it should affect the cohomology right?. But my real concern is the second part of the question. And if it is what you said then how does A comes into picture? It would be of great help if you could look it up and explain briefly or provide references.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was thinking of 2-complexes. Yes, the 3-cells do affect homology - if I remember correctly, this is how Eilenberg–MacLane spaces are constructed (by attaching the appropriate $n$-cells).